# PHP -- replace text in an array constructed from file php function

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have string and I would like to remove words which are part of the string and  in the array.  The array was created using the file function and the preg_replace function to delete patterns from the array occurring within a sentence.

Although, I am not getting errors, the replace is not working. I would really appreciate any help, I have been trying to get it to work these last 3 days but I haven't managed to do so :( and it is driving me crazy.

This is what I have done so far:

PHP code:

```
$test=file('files/stop_words.txt');
echo $test;

$no_stop=str_replace('|$test|', 'lllll', $sentence);
echo "<br>" .$no_stop;
```

Stop_words.txt file excerpt:

```
|alone|
|along|
|alongside|
|already|
|also|
|although|
|always|
|am|
|amid|
|amidst|
|among|
|amongst|
|an|
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding a sample sentence so you can see it working.

I swapped out file with file_get_contents so that you could remove the | on each side before doing the check.

str_replace can accept an array, but it must be setup for exact matches, so having "|among|" instead of just "among" would hinder as well.

```
$sentence = "I stood alone in the yard";

$test = file_get_contents('files/stop_words.txt'); // Load in as a string

$test = str_replace("|", "", $test); // Remove unneeded |
$testList = explode("\n", $test); // Turn into an array

$filtered_sentence = str_replace($testList, 'lllll', $sentence); // Pass array into str_replace

echo $filtered_sentence;
```

Comment: Thanks Asperon, I would not have I have close, yet so far. It works .